# How to open Microsoft outlook app from android browser using custom protocol?

Tags: javascript, android, html, outlook, custom-protocol

The below code works in iOS browsers but doesn't work in android browser. does anyone used custom protocol to launch outlook from android? Appreciated your help.

> ms-outlook://compose?to=example@email.com&subject=Subject&body=Message

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you can do this with Outlook.**

Outlook for Android app must have implemented ***[Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)*** to handle `ms-outlook://` protocol and some methods to parse parameters in your url 
`compose?to=example@email.com&subject=Subject&body=Message`

Comment: they have implemented, because I am able to open the app using just `ms-outlook://` but unable to pass any parameters. If I passes any parameters it won't launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send new message in the Outlook app on Android, you need to use next url: **ms-outlook://emails/new?to=example@mail.com&subject=subject&body=body**